# Excel Column value recognize and update in particular column

Tags: excel

Hi I don't know much in Excel Formula , I have a simple requirement , Please help me to solve this .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqtvI.png)

How can i write excel formula , Please check the image ,i have Some columns , i want to separate each column value based on days . 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be easier to use a pivottable to do this, see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-A9A84538-BFE9-40A9-A8E9-F99134456576)

Comment: I want to solve by IF condition ,  please let me know how can i solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter this in cell `C2` and drag across the rest of the range, making sure the headers in `C1`, `D1` and `E1` match the text string you are looking for in column B:

```
=IF($B2=C$1,$A2,"")
```

Comment: Hi ,  What if i have Data with  28 days , 45 days , 62 days. How can i use greater or lesser command .If 28 days is cell value , i should get it in 30 days column .